# Access app.buttons in Xcode UITest without having any usable text for referencing.

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, webpage-screenshot, fastlane

So I am trying to get `fastlane screenshot` working and that means getting Xcode UITest working...I build an Ionic app that uses a 3-bar symbol as a slide-out button and that sort of thing is trivial with webapps.

However, when I use uITest record, it misinterprets the button and ends up representing  like this

`app.buttons[""].tap()`

When it tries to run the saved UI commands, it obviously chokes on this and crashes the test...is there any other way to represent the button other then using its label text like that?

It would seem to be that it could use the ID or NAME for the button identifier, but I have yet to find that solution for this problem anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give the button an AccessibilityIdentifier, which is a property that will only be read by the UI Tests and which does not require there to be any readable text.

You can also give the button an AccessibilityLabel, which will enable your button to be used by people who are using accessibility, such as with screen readers or other such devices.

Both of these properties can be read by the XCUIElementQuery, which means you will be able to use, e.g., `app.buttons["slide_out"].tap()`.

In order to do this, you set the accessibilityIdentifier / accessibilityLabel explicitly in code (`button.accessibilityIdentifier = "slide_out"`, for example) or in the Storyboard (under properties; see screenshot).

[image: Here is the Storyboard area in question]

If, on the other hand, there's a timing issue because you need to wait for the element to appear, I recommend Joe Masilotti's blog post about custom helpers in XCUITest: http://masilotti.com/xctest-helpers/

Comment: i almost hate to say this, but it turned out that the real issue was that i needed to introduce delays into the testing script...i felt i needed to put that here in case someone else run into the same problem,, but again thxs again for the interesting info!

Comment: Don't hate to say it. Instead, check out Joe Masilotti's XCUITest custom helpers: http://masilotti.com/xctest-helpers/

He's found a really good solution for introducing delays in the testing script.

Answer (score 0):

Tipp:
In case, anyone tries to access buttons from within an IONIC app and doesn't find out about how to code the 'accessibilityIdentifier' in that IONIC .html and .ts files...

```
aria-label="myLabel"
```

in the button element does the trick; id, name and so on don't.